# multilingual joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, multilingual, joomla-extensions

I have read that Joomla 2+ has multilingual abilities where a content writer can write an article into several languages and Joomla can display them based on browser default languages or some kind of flag UI.

I am looking for a Joomla 2+ tutorial that explains everything I need to do to get this to work? Is it the same as in 1.7 or is this different for 2.5?

Does anyone have a tutorial or where I can find docs for this?

Thanks,

Comment: it's improved in 2.5, but it's best if you check on joomla website for tutorials, try using google

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the native Joomla multilingual option, here are a two good links for you:

[Building Multi-lingual Joomla 2.5 Sites - OS Training](http://bit.ly/LpPoV2)
[Joomla multilingual webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnhVVtyejPg)

Your other choice is to use an extension, either [Joomfish](http://www.joomfish.net) or [FaLang](http://www.faboba.com/en/composants/falang.html).  I've made site's using all three. Joomfish for Joomla 2.5 has only recently been released and I think still has a few rough edges, FaLang works well.

Personally I've become a convert to the native Joomla option. The initial setup takes a bit of figuring out, but it has worked well for me.

Good luck

Comment: I found the OS Training to be a very good guide for making sure everything gets turned on properly. Just used it yesterday!

Comment: Yes @DavidFritsch , first time through, getting everything turned on properly isn't completely intuitive. Once you work through all the setup though, everything else seems to fall nicely into place.